# Using same browser session in different cases

Tags: python, selenium

In the below code am trying to use the same browser session in different test cases, but after running its observed that two different browser sessions are opened for each test case. Please guide me to fix this issue:

```
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(
            executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe")

class Test_Trials(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1(self):
        driver1.set_page_load_timeout(20)
        driver1.get("http://192.168.221.238:8180/tnp/")
        driver1.maximize_window()

    def test_2(self):
        driver1.find_element_by_id("j_username").send_keys("admin")
        driver1.find_element_by_name("j_password").send_keys("admin1001")
        driver1.find_element_by_class_name("gwt-Button").click()
        driver1.set_page_load_timeout(20)
```

Comment: To use the same session you need to add "set up"-method with the ability to login via cookies or Local Storage (it depends on the realization it in your app).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use pytest with module setup, initilazing your driver before class execution:

```
class Test_Trials(unittest.TestCase):

  def setup_module(module):
      driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(
          executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe")
```

Or class method:

```
 @classmethod
 def setup_class(cls):
      driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(
          executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe")
```

Full documentation: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring and initializing `driver1` inside the class. Alternatively, only declare it inside the class (initialize with `None`), and initialize it in the `setupClass` method like this:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe")
```